# python 正規表現で和集合 | を使用した場合の group() で想定した出力が得られない

Tags: python, 正規表現

pythonの正規表現について質問です。正規表現で、|を用いてマッチを行なったのですが、意図しないNoneが出力されてしまいます。どなたか、理由をご教授いただけますと幸いです。

**現状のコード**

```
pattern = r"b(\d)|a(\d)"
sentence = "a4"

result = re.match(pattern, sentence)
if result:
    print(result.group())
    print(result.group(1))
```

**意図する出力**

```
a4
4
```

**実際の出力**

```
a4
None
```

**環境**

```
python3 --version
-Python 3.7.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

正規表現のグループ番号は、パターン文字列の内容に関わらず、`(`が登場する順に1から割り振られます。
そのため、 `b(\d)|a(\d)` というパターンであれば

- `b(\d)`側の`(\d)`が1
- `a(\d)`側の`(\d)`が2

と割り振られます。このことを踏まえると次のような結果になるはずです。

- `"a4"`の場合

  - マッチ全体 `a4`
  - グループ1 `None`
  - グループ2 `4`
- `"b5"`の場合

  - マッチ全体 `b5`
  - グループ1 `5`
  - グループ2 `None`

---

以下はPythonには適用されません。

一部の正規表現エンジンは名前付きグループを定義できます。更に複数の名前付きグループを統合する機能を持つものもあります。例えば[.NETの正規表現](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named_matched_subexpression)では次のようにでき、名前付きグループ `num` で参照できます。

```
b(?<num>\d)|a(?<num>\d)
```

- `"a4"`の場合

  - マッチ全体 `a4`
  - グループnum `4`
- `"b5"`の場合

  - マッチ全体 `b5`
  - グループnum `5`

[Pythonは名前付きグループを定義できますが、グループは統合できない](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#index-17)ようです。

Answer (score 0):

公式ドキュメントから:

[Regular Expression HOWTO - Grouping](https://docs.python.org/3.10/howto/regex.html#grouping)

> **Groups are numbered starting with 0. Group 0 is always present; it’s the whole RE**, so match object methods all have group 0 as their default argument.

> **Subgroups are numbered from left to right, from 1 upward**. Groups can be nested; to determine the number, just count the opening parenthesis characters, going from left to right.

```py
import re

pattern = r"b(\d)|a(\d)"
sentence = "a4"

result = re.match(pattern, sentence)
if result:
    print(result.group(0))
    print(result.group(1, 2))

#
a4
(None, '4')
```

蛇足ながら、今回の場合は以下の様にしてもよいかと思います。

```
import re

pattern = r"[ab](\d)"
sentence = "a4"

result = re.match(pattern, sentence)
if result:
    print(result.group())
    print(result.group(1))
```

ちなみに [regex · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) では同名の named group で capture が可能です。

```py
import regex as re

pattern = r"b(?P<num>(\d))|a(?P<num>(\d))"
sentence = "a4"

result = re.match(pattern, sentence)
if result:
    print(result.group())
    print(result.group('num'))

#
a4
4
```